# Are function variables concurrency-safe in golang?

Tags: function, go, concurrency, goroutine

I have following types declared

```
type TestFn func(id int, ctx context.Context) error

var Func1 = TestFn(func(id int, ctx context.Context) error {
  // do some work -- the execution block is concurrent safe
}

var Func2 = TestFn(func(id int, ctx context.Context) error {
  // do some work
}

var Func3 = TestFn(func(id int, ctx context.Context) error {
  // do some work
}

func Execute()
   for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
      go Func1(i, ctx)
      go Func2(i, ctx)
      go Func3(i, ctx)
   }
}
```

As `Func1`, `Func2`, `Func3` are global variables and assigned to functions, can I run same function in multiple go routines with different params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is simple: no value is safe for concurrent access from multiple goroutines (without synchronization) where at least one of the accesses is a write.

Your example only reads the function variables, so it is safe. If there would be a goroutine running concurrently with the execution of `Execute()` that would modify the function variables, that would not be safe. But this doesn't happen in your example.

Note: your function variables are of course written once, during package initialization. That happens in a single goroutine before `main()` starts.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies/clears out my questions

Answer (score -1):

Yes, your code works.

---

You would have issues if a goroutine tried to reassign the value of `FuncXX` while another one tries to start that same `FuncXX` -- this would be a race condition.